# I'm getting error in node using gulp and gulp-livereload

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-livereload

i downloaded livereload extension but it's not working, here's the error.

`Error: watching ./src/*.css: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)`

```js
var
    gulp = require("gulp"),
    livereload = require("gulp-livereload");

gulp.task("reload-css", function() {
    gulp.src('./src/*.css')
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task("default", function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('./src/*.css', ['reload-css']);
});
```

So what should i do now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you're using gulp 4, but write gulp 3 syntax. Try

```
gulp.watch('./src/*.css', gulp.series('reload-css'))
```

Check out the [gulp 4 docs.](https://gulpjs.org/API.html#gulp-watch-globs-opts-fn)
This [post](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/) highlight the differences in the new gulp.